# isn't JSR 286 (portlets) already finalized?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, portlet, jsr286

isn't JSR 286 (portlets) already finalized? However when I [download it](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286), the first page writes `send comments about this document to: jsr-286-comments@jcp.org` so my question is is jsr 286 finalized or not yet finalized (meaning will change in the future)

Btw, i've downloaded the [zip file](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286) and there is are 2 pdfs, 1 with "all track changes". Which pdf should i read if i want to learn everything about jsr 286?

Comment: How much all about do you want? About the document as it is now or about the history of the document?

Comment: @Donal Fellows . i have zero experience, and i need to do a jsr project now so which would be more suitable? btw is the "all track changes" only necessary if we already know the first version and want to  "update" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's finalized, and it's considered "final". 
But specifications might have errors, and corrections will be addressed in so-called "maintenance" releases.
There's for instance a maintenance release of the EJB 3.1 specs, dated Dec 07, 2010.

Concerning the PDFs, I'm pretty sure the content is the same. But "allTrackChanges" highlights the changes with a vertical bar on the left. As this doesn't matter to you, read the regular PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Portlet 2.0 (JSR 286) has been finished (and shipping as product) for a while now. You probably want to read `PortletSpec_20.pdf`, unless you just want to know the bits that have changed since JSR 168, in which case you want `PortletSpec_20-allTrackChanges.pdf`.

> the first page writes send comments about this document to: jsr-286-comments@jcp.org

Well, the expert group needs to solicit feedback somehow. There may be new versions or maintenance releases in the future.